# Can we use constant and returns keyword and a;change the state of the variables in solidity?

Tags: solidity

the warnings say that the function is declared as view and those lines are changing the state. i want a return statement but also want to do the addition and subtraction in the function body(ie., change the state). is it possible in solidity? 
(this code is a part of the ERC20 token

```
function _transferToken(address _from, address _to, uint _value) constant public returns (string) 
 {
    // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
    if(_to == 0x0)
    {
        return "Invalid address";
    }

    // Check if the sender has enough
    else if(balanceOf[_from] < _value)
    {
        return "insufficient tokens";
    }

    // Check for overflows
    else if(balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to])
    {
        return "Transaction failed";
    }

    else
    {
        // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_from] = balanceOf[_from] - _value; ***warning***
        // Add the same to the recipient
        balanceOf[_to]=balanceOf[_to] + _value; *****warning*****
        return("Successful");

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a function as `view`, you must not modify the state. This is not enforced yet, the compiler only raises a warning. But what you are planning on doing is not possible with a `view` function.

Calling a `view` function from off chain doesn't cost you any ether because you don't change the state or run any computations on the actual blockchain.

Besides, you shouldn't use the `constant` modifier for functions anymore. It is an alias for `view` and is deprecated.
It will be dropped in version 0.5.0 as stated in the official documentation [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help!